# Extension of $A_6$ by outer automorphism of $S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be an extension of $A_6$ by an exterior automorphism of $S_6$ of order $2$. How does this group look like, is it just $S_6$, or where is the difference?

Comment: The outer automorphism of $S_6$ interchanges conjugacy classes of $(ab)$ and  $(pq)(rs)(tu)$, while other conjugacy classes will be fixed. So the effect of outer automorphism on $A_6$ may be same as effect of conjugation by $(12)$ on $A_6$; **possibly** it is $S_6$. (I am not sure).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The group you describe is isomorphic to  ${\rm PGL}(2,9)$.

There is another such group, which is often known as $M_{10}$, the stabilizer of a point in the Mathieu group $M_{11}$. This is also an extension of $A_6$ by an outer automorphism, but in that case it is a non-split extension, so I am not sure whether you would describe it as an extension by an outer automorphism iof order $2$.

The full automorphism group of $A_6 \cong {\rm PSL}(2,9)$ is the group ${\rm P \Gamma L}(2,9)$, which has order $1440$ and has three non-isomorphic subgroups of index $2$, namely $S_6$, ${\rm PGL}(2,9)$, and $M_{10}$.